# getElementById(...).onclick doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, flask, navbar

I'm trying to display a sidebar that can be toggled on and off, I have a navbar at the top that contains a tag with the id="toggle" for which I added an eventListener (which waits for the HTML to be loaded before running the javascript code) and a corresponding function that should collapse/expand the side menu. However when I try to run the code nothing happens. Any help would be great!

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- navbar -->
        <div id="navbar">
          <a href="" id="toggle">&#9776; Menu</a>
          <a href="">Forget me</a>
        </div>

        <!-- sidebar -->
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <a href="">About</a>
          {% for room in chatroom %}
          <a href="">{{ room }}</a>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

And the js file, which is in the 'static' folder:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  document.getElementById("toggle").onclick = function() {

    var sidebar = document.getElementById("mySidenav");

    if (sidebar.style.width === "250px") {
      sidebar.style.width = "0";

    } else {
      sidebar.style.width = "250px";
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues without testing any code:

1. Your closing body tag needs to be `</body>`, and;
2. The `toggle` link will navigate away from the page, and you will need to prevent this. You can do so by changing the `toggle` element to a `button type="button"`, or adding `preventDefault()` into your click handler Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Can you please explain why I have to change to a button element? Some code example seemed to work the <a> tag?

Comment: In short, the browser will always follow the `href` target. When it's "" it will still 'go' to the current page. A couple of ways to still use `<a>`: 1. Place a javascript function in the href, e.g. `href="javascript:changeSidebar()"`, 2. Add the `event.preventDefault()` function into your JS (plenty of explanations on Google here).